# Android linear layout inversed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am encountering a strange behaviour with linear layout. It displays the layout as if the weights were inversed.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="5">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/holder_list_lines"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

    </View>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/holder_list_added_lines"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" >

    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

However black view takes as much space as it would if the weight would be 1. But the weight is 4 so something is wrong.
There is also one more weird thing. In the graphical layout mode, this layout is shown correctly, the weights are only inversed when displayed on device (Asus ME302C).

Comment: This works as expected on my device and in the graphical layout mode. Could be a device specific problem.

Comment: Possibly, however I have tried it on the emulator and even the emulator displays it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the weightsum and keep the weights for the views as such

Comment: @Jiju Could you explain this a bit ? Isn't this how the weight sum is supposed to work ?

Comment: @Jiju, I would also be very in the explanation.

Comment: There is no need to specify the weightsum for the layout. It will automatically calculate from children's weight.

Answer (score 0):

Change `match_parent` to `wrap_content` in `Views`, or switch the weights:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="5">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/holder_list_lines"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

    </View>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/holder_list_added_lines"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" >

    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Changing views layout_height or layout_width does not improve the situation. It is still displayed with weights inversed.